# New StreamReader class doesn't accept filename

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been trying to get out a demo for MVC 6.0 and I find that I can't read a file anymore using `StreamReader` class as it doesn't accept a string anymore. 
So code like this

```
StreamReader reader= new StreamReader("filename.txt")
```

is not valid?

I am using .NET Core 1.0

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @jonskeet updated the question with the. Net version

Comment: You're certain you're not building against .NET Core? It should definitely be there for the desktop framework.

Comment: @jonskeet Yes looks like I am building against. Net Core 1.0

Comment: Right, so that's the version number that your question should refer to.

Comment: @jonskeet thanks, updated the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think they've removed it as a StreamReader shouldn't be responsible for creating streams - it's a violation of the Single Responsibility Principle.

You'll need to create a [FileStream](https://dotnet.github.io/api/System.IO.FileStream.html#System_IO_FileStream) or similar in order to get the same functionality

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\test.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    // do stuff.
}
```

Comment: Or more simply, use `File.OpenText`.

Comment: If you use the File class from System.IO in a .Net Core project (for example, to use File.OpenText), you'll probably also need to specify "System.IO.File.OpenText" since ControllerBase also has a File class

Comment: Or more simply for writing, use [`File.CreateText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx).